# after starting sub thread, main thread seems to stop and wait, rather than providing progress info

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a thread that is spawned from a running Flask server with the following structure shown below. My problem is it works, except after the second sub-process is started it just stops and appears to waits there. No progress info is generated and the print statements never print even after both sub-threads complete.  Thanks for any help.

```
class One(threading.Thread):
      ... 

Class Two(threading.Thread):
      ...

Class myfirstthread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, sid, socketio, *args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sid=sid
        self.socketio = socketio
        self=.args = args 

.... 
    def run(self): 
        w=One()
        wtwo=Two()
        w.start()
        wtwo.start()

        while not finished:
            print "while started"
            self.socketio.emit("progress message",{data},self.sid, namespace="/myspace")

        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: what is `finished` and where do you set it?

Comment: @mata has a great question. Suppose `finished` is a global variable still set from a previous run. For debug, check `finished` at the very top of `run(self)` to see if its in the state you want.

Comment: Finished is set inside the main thread - myfirstthread -- it is a called by after both sub threads check in .. for example :

Comment: thread One and Two each have a instance of myMainThread and there is a method in myMainThread that waits for both sub-threads to callback after completion .. so after both callback, self.finished is set to True.

Comment: Even with while not finished . changed to while True there is no difference.